# How to add a context indicator to a flipview

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-8, gallery

I created a simple Windows 8 app with a single page and a flipview. My goal is to slide through a set of images. Microsoft suggests to use a context indicator for image galleries with larger amount of images (I have 25 photos).

So for starters: I hope that flipview is the correct tool to my needs?

And how can I add a context indicator to an existing flipview? So far I added the flipview to the xaml file:

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView"  Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black"/>
```

Also I added some images in C#:

```
ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/gallery/IMG_0001.jpg"));

FlipViewItem flipvw1 = new FlipViewItem();
flipvw1.Background = brush1;

flipView.Items.Add(flipvw1);
```

etc...

Comment: There's also this: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/04/lets-code-build-your-own-flipview-page.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this blog post that describes how to implement one:

http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/08/24/A-CXAML-FlipView-Context-Indicator-for-Windows-8.aspx

Also Callisto includes the implementation that you can just grab from NuGet:

https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/FlipViewIndicator/FlipViewIndicator.cs

Comment: how to add the callisto flipviewindicator from the code behind ?

Comment: `MyGrid.Children.Add(new FlipViewIndicator { FlipView = MyFlipView });`

Comment: i'm assuming MyFlipView here is the name of the FlipView element which would be a string ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a string"?